# Virtual Attributes: No route matches {:controller=>"phone", :action=>"new"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller "find_numbers", which I'm using to submit a form to the Twilio API. Before it submits though, I'd like to validate against two form fields, which aren't in the data model for this controller. The fields are :name, and :original_number

So, in my find_numbers model, I added attr_accessor :name, attr_accessor :originial number to run a validates command under it.

After doing that and submitting the form as invalid, I get the error :

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:controller=>"phone", :action=>"new"}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

I'm not sure why it says there's no roots, but I'm not sure why it's accessing that anyways. I want it to POST to find_numbers

The find_numbers/new template

```
 <%= form_tag("/find_numbers", :method => "post", :id => "new_user" ) do %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>    

    <%= label_tag(:name, "What Are You Tracking?") %>
     <%= text_field_tag(:name) %>

    <%= label_tag(:original_number, "Your Orginal Number") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:original_number) %>


    <%= label_tag(:in_postal_code, "Near US postal code (e.g. 94117):") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:in_postal_code) %>

    <%= label_tag(:near_number, "Near this other number (e.g. +4156562345)") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:near_number) %>

    <%= label_tag(:contains, "Matching this pattern (e.g. 415***EPIC):") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:contains) %>  

    <%= submit_tag("Search", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary") %>


  <% end %>
```

here's my find_number model

```
class FindNumber < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessor :name
    attr_accessor :original_number

    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :original_number, presence: true

end
```

Here's my Find_number controller

```
class FindNumbersController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @user = current_user
    end

    def create
        @user = current_user
        client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@user.twilio_account_sid, @user.twilio_auth_token)

        search_params = {}
          %w[in_postal_code near_number contains].each do |p|
            search_params[p] = params[p] unless params[p].nil? || params[p].empty?
          end

        local_numbers = client.account.available_phone_numbers.get('US').local
        @numbers = local_numbers.list(search_params)

        unless @numbers.empty?
        render 'find_numbers/show'
        else
        flash.now[:error] = "Sorry, We Couldn't Find Any Numbers That Matched Your Search! Maybe Something Simpler?"    
        render 'find_numbers/new'
        end
    end

    def show


    end

end
```

Any thoughts on accomplishing this would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**

Routes.rb file

```
    Dct::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :phones, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :find_numbers, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]  

  match '/find_numbers',  to: 'find_numbers#new'  

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/login',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

  root  to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/product_demo', to: 'static_pages#product_demo'

  match '/pricing', to: 'plans#index'

  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
```

**Edit**

Here is the server log, of what happened when I hit submit

http://stepanp.com/railserror.jpg

Also, here's the find_numbers/show view

Comment: Could you also post the relevant part of your `routes.rb`?

Comment: Just updated the post :)

Comment: I see your reasoning, and since I hacked together the form it makes sense. The first view file in the post is the find_numbers/new template. Do you have any thoughts on it? I'll also update the question now to specify more clearly that that is the view template for find_numbers/new

Comment: Also, I'm sure this has nothing to do with the problem you're facing, but is there a reason you have two routes leading to `find_numbers#new` in your routes.rb?

Comment: Oops, I think I might have had that before adding the resource in the routes file. I removed it, and now access the new view via /find_numbers/new , though No route matches {:controller=>"phone", :action=>"new"} still shows up. 

Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Yes, it's really weird. I just looked at server log, and attached that as well. I interpreted it to say that there's an error on line 20, of the find_numbers controller on line 20. That's where it says render 'find_numbers/show'. It's weird though, because since it should have validated against that, it should not have seen that line. 

Do you see anything suspicious in the image?

Comment: Ooo! The problem was in the show view -- I had <%= form_tag(:controller => "phone", :action => "new" ) do %> . This means that the intial form did not validate properly, but at least this part of the error is fixed! Thanks for your guidance. If you could add one of your comments as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: So the solution was to change "phone" to "phones" then?

Comment: Yes sir. I also realized that I didn't have the validation figured out at all. Looking at the code for create, it doesn't actually check that the virtual attributes name, and original_number are valid. If you get the chance to take a look at that error as well, I would really appreciate it -- > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715314/validating-virtual-attributes-in-forms-undefined-method-valid-for-namesym

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've posted, the only other thing that looks suspicious to me is that you presumably have a PhonesController (plural) since you've declared resources :phones, but the routing error seems to occur because it is looking for a PhoneController (singular).

Comment: Thanks for sticking through this with me!